# Cannot render array items in v-for select menu

Tags: javascript, vue.js

As a newbie to Vue.js, I'm trying to render this array:

```
       countries: ["US", "UK", "EU" ]
```

Into a select menu:

```
<select>
  <option disabled value="">Your Country</option>
  <option v-for="(index, c) in countries" :key="index">{{ c }}</option>
</select>
```

And put `UK` as default selected item.
But instead of Country codes, just `cuntries` being shown in the menu.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You say "store"  are you using Vuex then?

Comment: Yes, but never mind, that's another story that I've resolved.

Comment: Ok good luck on the rest of your adventure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you want and set "UK" as a default add a 'v-model' to your select which you probably want anyway

```
<select v-model="selected">
  <option v-for="(c,index) in countries" :key="index" >{{ c }}</option>
</select>
```

Then in your data object set `selected` to your default value.

```
data(){
  return{
     countries: ["US", "UK", "EU" ],
     selected: "UK",
  }
}
```

Modified working example here -> https://jsfiddle.net/skribe/0wmnkfpz/6/

Comment: Please modify your answer above rather than putting it in comments.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have the order of index and c flipped. It should be:

```
<option v-for="(c, index) in countries" :key="index">{{ c }}</option>
```

See examples on https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

Comment: @Babr then you have  something else wrong.  KJ789's answer should work.  See here  https://jsfiddle.net/skribe/0wmnkfpz/2/

Comment: Alright, perhapas there is some typo in my original array. In any case How can I put `UK` as defaut here?